# WPF BindingGroup.UpdateSources() only updating once per instance

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a wpf, single page, app. The xaml has a rough outline as below:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="Stack1Options">
    <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup />
    </StackPanel.BindingGroup>
    <Label Content="Field 1" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Field1" Text="{Binding Path=BindingSection1.Field1, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
    <Label Content="Field 2" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Field2" Text="{Binding Path=BindingSection1.Field2, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <Button x:Name="SaveStack1OptionsBtn" Click="SaveOptions">Save Stack 1 Options</Button>
        <Button x:Name="RevertStack1OptionsBtn" Click="RevertOptions>Revert Stack 1 Options</Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel x:Name="Stack2Options">
    <StackPanel.BindingGroup>
        <BindingGroup />
    </StackPanel.BindingGroup>
    <Label Content="Field 3" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Field3" Text="{Binding Path=BindingSection2.Field3, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
    <Label Content="Field 4" />
    <TextBox x:Name="Field4" Text="{Binding Path=BindingSection2.Field4, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <Button x:Name="SaveStack1OptionsBtn" Click="SaveOptions">Save Stack 2 Options</Button>
        <Button x:Name="RevertStack1OptionsBtn" Click="RevertOptions>Revert Stack 2 Options</Button>
    </UniformGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

etc. with 4 `StackPanels` containing various settings for the app. In my code behind I have the `SaveOptions` and `RevertOptions` methods as below:

```
private void SaveOptions(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel parent = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((UniformGrid)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as DependencyObject));
    parent.BindingGroup.UpdateSources();
}

private void RevertOptions(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel parent = (StackPanel)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((UniformGrid)VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(sender as DependencyObject));
    foreach (var binding in parent.BindingGroup.BindingExpressions)
        binding.UpdateTarget();
}
```

So that whichever 'Save' or 'Revert' button is clicked, it will update the sources of the relevant BindingGroup, or revert the changes of the TextBoxes from the relevant sources respectively.

Revert works fine each time. Save works fine, the very first time it is used after opening the app - if you then make further changes (on any of the StackPanels) and try to save, these changes will not be pushed through to the binding source. And I have no idea why, the bindings are clearly correct otherwise the first save would not work, but I have no idea as to why it then gets "stuck" after that, if anyone can advise?

I have found the below question:

[WPF: What can cause a binding source to not be updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1651015/wpf-what-can-cause-a-binding-source-to-not-be-updated/1651873#1651873)

Though this is obviously suggesting that `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` would avoid the issue of the source not updating, where I am already using Explicit.

Comment: Do you have any validation rules for your binding group?

Comment: No, don't have any validation rules in place.

Comment: If you give your binding group a name, and then specify the name in each of your bindings, does this solve the problem?

Comment: Are u trying with different inputs or same inputs ?

Comment: Adding a name to the binding group and setting the BindingGroupName on each field doesn't seem to make any difference. I am trying with different inputs.

Comment: I recreated your code and couldn't reproduce. I'd like to see the viewmodel property definitions for `BindingSection1`, `BindingSection1.Field1`, etc. Does anything else touch `BindingSection1` etc.? Did you put a breakpoint in the `Field1` setter and then try a second save? From the code I've seen, I can't rule out the possibility that the `Field1` property is being set, but on the wrong instance. Not the most likely thing, but *something* is causing it, clearly.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of response, I redid my Model and ViewModel last night, and now seems to be saving correctly. I think you were probably right @EdPlunkett in that somewhere I was referring to the wrong instance and that was causing the issue!